# What if the public key is lost? Is that a security issue?

Tags: public-key, openssh

DSA or RSA has a private key and pubic key; the private must be kept safe and the public key uploaded to a host you want to access.

But what if the public key is lost, or revealed to everyone, like in a blog post?  Is that a security issue ?

Comment: i tried to make your english easier to read - i hope that i did not change the meaning, but the question was being flagged for closure as it was.

Comment: I've noticed people seem to think this is an issue because of the recent Github incident. But the issue was that people could add their own public keys to your repo with out you wanting it.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not an issue in the slightest: it's meant to be public anyway.
According to what you use you key for, you may even NEED it to be available to everyone (think gpg keys for signing email).

As long as your private key is safe, you've nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem in everyone knowing the public key.  you can share it anywhere you like - even in a blog.  it is only important to keep the private key secret.